# Retrieving integer datatype from firebase realtime to Android textview

Tags: android

I'm trying to retrieve the integer values from Firebase Realtime to Android Studio textview. But the integer values doesn't show in my textview

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
 @Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.getValue(Integer.class)!=null){

        String key = snapshot.getKey();
        if (key.equals("WaterTemperature")) {

            int first = snapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
            waterTempVal.setText(first);
        }

        if (key.equals("WaterTurbidity")) {

            int second = snapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
            waterTurbidityVal.setText(second);
        }

        if (key.equals("WaterPh")) {

            int third = snapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
            waterPhVal.setText(third);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong can someone enlighten me

Comment: Could it have to do something with the OnDataChange Method? Seems to me that this would only trigger if data changes in the firebase db. Have you checked if the code is executed ?

Comment: When i tried to run the program there is no error but when I tried going in debug it just said that my integer is not a valid resource id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, just convert to toString OR wrapString

```
int first = snapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
 waterTempVal.setText(first.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but it shows error in this "waterTempVal.setText(first.toString());" part

Comment: check the data is null or not! if data null assign "" or anything you want